# Filter List based on another list

Tags: list, filter, compare

i have two lists based on other objects.

```
List<Emyployee> emyployeeList;
List<Display> displayEmployeeList;
```

both of them have the id's of the employees, but the second list only have a few of them.
I want to filter the employeeList that i have all id's that arent in the displayEmployeeList.

how can i do that?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? If yes, please provide us your work.

Comment: yes i tried this, but obviously it doesnt work:
newEmyployeeList= emyployeeList.FindAll(x => x.id != displayEmployeeList[0].id);

Comment: Ok yes thats obviously not the correct way to do it. Because you are just taking care of the first element in `displayEmployeeList`. The first obvious solution would be to make two foreach loops. The other possible solution you could take for account would be to use [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If `displayEmployeeList` has *many items* you can find useful to create a kind of *index* (like that of RDBMS):

```
  // let id be integer
  HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(displayEmployeeList
    .Select(item => item.id)
  );

  // Just Linq where
  var result = emyployeeList
    .Where(item => !ids.Contains(item.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method and do it like the following:

```
employeeList.Zip(displayEmployeeList,(employee,display) => 
             {
                if(employee.Id != display.Id)
                  return employee;
             });
```